# Update Progress bar on Form1, when using a Mutex Multithread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, progress-bar, mutex

I'm trying to update a progress bar while data is being written to an MS Access Database. In order to make the writing to the database faster. I have broken up the data in my datatable into batches of 1000 rows, there is about 8500 in total. The batches then use the Mutex threading method to speed the process up.

I currently have on Form1 a button that starts the process of writing the data.

```
Private Sub PrepareData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrepareData.Click
        PrepareData.BackColor = Color.SlateGray
        Data_Preperation_Tasks()
End Sub
```

For context, this also occurs,

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Initialize the BackgroundWorker
        bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub bgWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.ProgressChanged
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(Sub()
                          Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
                      End Sub)
            Return
        Else
            ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
            ProgressBar1.Refresh()
        End If
End Sub
```

this then calls the sub:

```
Private Sub Data_Preperation_Tasks()
    'other code here that checks things

          Call Write_ProductDetails_ToDatabase_MutexMethod()
End Sub
```

the above subs are in the Public Class Form 1
Write_ProductDetails_ToDatabase_MutexMethod() is inside Module1

```
Module Module1

 Private Sub UpdateProgressBar(ByVal value As Integer)
        If Form1.IsHandleCreated Then
            Form1.Invoke(Sub()
                             Form1.ProgressBar1.Value = value
                             Form1.ProgressBar1.Refresh()
                         End Sub)
        Else
            Form1.ProgressBar1.Value = value
            Form1.ProgressBar1.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub Write_ProductDetails_ToDatabase_MutexMethod()

        Form1.Action3.Text = "Writing Product Details To Database"
        Form1.Action3.BackColor = Color.Orange
        Form1.Action3.Visible = True

        Dim sAppPath As String
        sAppPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath

        Dim connectionString As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sAppPath & "\BatchNumberUpload.MDB"
        Dim mutexName As String = "database_mutex"
        Dim mutex As Mutex = New Mutex(False, mutexName)

        Dim batchSize As Integer = 1000
        Dim threadCount As Integer = (InventoryTable.Rows.Count + batchSize - 1) \ batchSize ' Round up to the nearest integer
        Dim countdownEvent As CountdownEvent = New CountdownEvent(threadCount)

        Dim rowCount As Integer = 0 ' Keep track of the number of rows that have been written so far
        Dim totalRowCount As Integer = InventoryTable.Rows.Count

        Form1.ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
        Form1.ProgressBar1.Maximum = totalRowCount
        Form1.ProgressBar1.Visible = True
       
        'Start the BackgroundWorker
        Form1.bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()

        For i As Integer = 0 To InventoryTable.Rows.Count - 1 Step batchSize
            Dim batchRows = InventoryTable.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().Skip(i).Take(batchSize)

            ' Create a new thread for each batch of rows
            Dim thread = New Thread(Sub()
                                        ' Synchronize access to the database connection using a Mutex
                                        mutex.WaitOne()
                                        Try
                                            Using connection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
                                                Using command = New OleDbCommand()
                                                    command.Connection = connection
                                                    connection.Open()

                                                    For Each row In batchRows
                                                        Dim constring As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sAppPath & "\BatchNumberUpload.MDB"

                                                        Using con As New OleDbConnection(constring)

                                                            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO " & "`" & "BatchNumbers" & "`" & " Values(@BatchNumber,@ProductCode,@FirstLine,@SecondLine,@RRP,@SalePrice,@SaleEndDate,@Barcode)", con)


                                                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNumber", row.Item("BatchNumber"))
                                                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", row.Item("ProductCode"))
                                                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstLine", row.Item("FirstLine"))
                                                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondLine", row.Item("SecondLine"))
                                                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RRP", row.Item("RRP"))
                                                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalePrice", row.Item("SalePrice"))
                                                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleEndDate", row.Item("SaleEndDate"))
                                                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Barcode", row.Item("Barcode"))
                                                                con.Open()

                                                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                                                                con.Close()

                                                            End Using

                                                        End Using
                                                        rowCount += 1 ' Increment the number of rows that have been written so far
                                                        If rowCount Mod 10 = 0 Then
                                                            Dim progressPercentage As Integer = CInt(rowCount * 100 / totalRowCount)
                                                            Form1.bgWorker.ReportProgress(progressPercentage) ' Report progress to the background worker
                                                        End If

                                                    Next
                                                End Using
                                            End Using
                                        Finally
                                            mutex.ReleaseMutex()
                                            countdownEvent.Signal() ' Signal that the thread has completed
                                        End Try
                                    End Sub)
            thread.Start()
        Next

        ' Wait for all threads to complete before proceeding to the next subroutine
        countdownEvent.Wait()

        UpdateProgressBar(totalRowCount)

        Form1.Action3.Text = "Completed Writing To Database"
        Form1.Action3.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
        Form1.Action3Tick.Visible = True

        Form1.TimeRemaining.Text = "Completed"

    End Sub



End Module
```

My problem is no matter what i try i cant get ProgressBar1 back on Form1 to update /redraw to show it has progressed.
it will update at the end after the countdownEvent.Wait() as occurred.

also the form and all its controls are unresponsive while these treads run. which i kind of understand why, and that the these threads are not being run on the UI thread.

But is there a way to make the progressbar updated while this is running, or even keep the form responsive so it could be minimised? From the examples if have seen on stackoverflow i was not able to get working.

Comment: Why use invoke from a thread you’ve got report progress turned on for?  Why not just handle the report process event?

Comment: You are using default instances of forms and you don't understand how they work. I suggest that you read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html). If you want to be able marshal a call to the UI thread in code that has no direct access to a control created on that thread, you should be suing the `SynchronizationContext` class, so you should look into that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i will take a look into it and see if i can understand it. as i don't really understand how the mutex class works to be honest.

Comment: @jmcilhinney unfortunately i wasn't able to understand what it was in the link that related to what i was doing. i tried to look into the SynchronizationContext class. But i wasn't able to adapt that to my problem.

Comment: @Hursey im not sure how to implement what it is that your suggesting sorry.

Comment: @AndyAndromeda 1) I suggest that you more closely follow the example in [BackgroundWorker Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) (you might need to change the language from C# to VB in the drop-down towards the top-right-ish of the page).

Comment: @AndyAndromeda 2) Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](https://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @AndyAndromeda 3) Instead of creating the parameters every time, you can create the parameters *outside* the loop and then just change the .Value of each one.

Comment: @AndyAndromeda 4) It would be safer to specify the column names in the INSERT statement, as shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql).